# What is the C# data type for WINOLEAPI?

Tags: c#, com

I am using some native methods to bind to running objects in a COM-based application. One of the methods is the CreateBindCtx, which has the following signature (from MSDN)

```
WINOLEAPI CreateBindCtx(DWORD reserved, LPBC FAR * ppbc)
```

I have defined the wrapper to be

```
public static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);
```

But FXCop is complaining about the void return type. What should the .Net/C# data type be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);
```

One of the best places for pinvoke info is [PInvoke.Net](http://pinvoke.net)